# How to test webhooks in paypal sandbox?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have implemented paypal payment in my shop with the new paypal rest api.

I noticed the is no notification url any more to get a callback when i create a transaction. But i saw that there are now webhooks. So i configured some webhooks in paypal and would not like to test them.

But i can not find any tool or interface to test the webhooks. I do not mean the way to access them by the rest api. I want paypal to execute a request to my server when a payment is for e.g. revoked somehow.

Where can i tell paypal to execute webhook request?

Answer (score 0):

You need to setup the APN gateway.

In the developer account, you can log into the test accounts in sand box mode.
Next go to the account settings and look for APN.
You can setup the path to your test servers url and capture the "webhooks" there.

Hope this helps.